# Is it possible to Index framset, news feed or Iframe pages

Tags: indexing

I hope that it is okay that I ask this question here but I am trying to figure out a problem for my page.

I have the following code:

```html
<frameset cols="100%,*,100%">
  <frame src="michaeistheone.blogspot.com/"; scrolling="">
</frameset>
```

The code works for the page as it should. But I am wondering if it is possible either with this code or some similar code to display and update content from the url but if I click on a link on the page it opens a new page and not stay on the same url on my page.

The problem is that when it stays on the same page the pages cant be indexed for my site & my search box wont find any of the pages that is in the framset page. With other words I would like the page url pages to be displayed on my website and then work so google can index the pages so each page shows up on my website & so that my google search box will find every page from that url when used. I hope I made myself clear, sorry for not being the best on my english but I hope you understand what I am trying to do :D

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to happen. Can you better explain where the link you mention is located and what page you mean by "if I click on a link on the page"? i.e., is the link on your page or inside the iframe and which page you want to change etc.

Comment: Okoay sure. Okay here is a test page for you to see what I mean :) http://scandinavianstrength.com/baratest.html as you can see on the left a blogger blog is displayed. The thing is that when I click ona link on that blog my website url will be the same. I want the content from just that blog to be displayed on my website like in html and css so I can get the pages indexed and so the search engine can find the pages on my website, not on the blogger.com. For as now it is not possible with that code. Do you understand what I mean or? :) I will of course use my own blog for this :)

Comment: IMHO you should better stop using **frameset** tag. It is kind deprecated. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp (not supported for html5)